# Looping over files in a directory that end with .fastq.gz

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to loop over my files in my directory using a bash script, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I am looping over files that ends with `_1.fastq.gz` and `_2.fastq.gz`

here is the script

```
fastq_dir="../script"
for sampleID in "${fastq_dir}"/*.fastq.gz
do
    r1=$(find "$sampleID" -name "*_1.fastq.gz")
    r2=$(find "$sampleID" -name "*_2.fastq.gz")
    sample_name=$(basename "$samleID")
    salmon quant -i salmon_index -l A -1 "$r1" -2 "$r2" --validateMappings -o salmon_quant/"$sample_name"/
done
```

The command probably cannot find/see some of the files for a reason. I am expecting the salmon quant function to loop over `fastq` files and send the output to new directories corresponding to the `fastq` files names.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add an example directory listing and a description of what is happening instead of what you expect? I'm quite familiar with the command line but I don't understand the problem you are facing..

Comment: Add `echo` in front of your `salmon` command to see how bash builds the command / what is happening behind the scenes, maybe you can spot the error easily then.

Comment: `$sampleID` isn't a directory, why are you using `find` to search it?

Comment: There is a typo in this line: `sample_name=$(basename "$samleID")`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a serious problem in the code (variable `samleID` not assigned).  The report that it produces includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Logs will be written to salmon_quant/SRR2147155_1.fastq.gz/logs
[2024-03-02 16:45:42.364] [jointLog] [info] setting maxHashResizeThreads to 8
Exception : [Error: The index version file salmon_index/versionInfo.json doesn't seem to exist.  Please try re-building the salmon index.]
salmon quant was invoked improperly.
For usage information, try salmon quant --help
Exiting. this is what I am getting. However, I am following the same code of a tutor, which seems to work with him.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is setting `$sampleID` to each `.fastq.gz` file, alternating between `_1` and `_2` each time. You don't want each file in a separate iteration.

Change your loop to just match `_1.fastq.gz`. Then replace `_1` with `_2` to get the other filename. And remove the suffix to get the common sample name.

```
for r1 in "${fastq_dir}"/*_1.fastq.gz
do
    r2=${r1/_1.fastq.gz/_2.fastq.gz}
    sample_name=${r1%_1.fastq.gz}
    salmon quant -i salmon_index -l A -1 "$r1" -2 "$r2" --validateMappings -o salmon_quant/"$sample_name"/
done
```

Comment: OK, let's remove the comments then

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Barmar.. your code worked perfectly. I am just wondering why my command wasn't working although I almost copied it from a tutorial. of course, after changing the path etc.

Comment: Did you read the first line of my answer? It explains what's wrong with your code. You process the `_1` and `_2` files in different iterations of the loop, but they need to be in the same iteration.